# Caracteres extraños al descargar un xml

Tags: xml, asp

He implementado código para descargar un archivo XML desde una url. Cuando el XML contiene caracteres extraños como `ñ`, `°`, etc. estos no se muestran de forma correcta: "CHA?RAL,N?

Si yo accedo directamente a la url me muestra los caracteres como corresponde.

¿Existe una forma de convertirlo para que desaparezcan y sean visualizados de forma correcta? Intenté con el ISO-8859-1 (que viene en el XML) y aun así siguen apareciendo.

Éste es el código que utilizo para la descarga:

```
private sub DownloadFile(file, folio, tipo)
  Set GetConnection = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  GetConnection.Open "get", file, False
  GetConnection.Send 
  ResponsePage = GetConnection.responseText
  Response.addHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "nombreArchivo"
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
  Response.Write ResponsePage
  Response.Flush()
  Response.End()
  Set GetConnection = Nothing
end sub
```

Comment: ¿Se ve mal cuando se muestra en el navegador o cuando lo abres en un editor de texto ?

Comment: Al momento de abrirlo en el editor de texto, en el navegador se ve bien